Android Kotlin run two coroutines in row
I am trying to run to run two coroutine launches in row. How can I archive this?
the first tries to get an Duration. When that is Successful the collect should stop and the second launch in my coroutine should run.
I do not know if this is the right way. But I need to get the Duration first and then process the second part.
ech part alone works. but not togeher, because collect is blocking. I also tried to do return@collect, but does not work
@Singleton
class AddDayReminderNotification(
    private val notificationUseCases: NotificationUseCases,
    private val dayUseCases: DayUseCases,
    private val weekUseCases: WeekUseCases,
    private val settingsUseCases: SettingsUseCases
) {
    suspend fun addNotification(context: Context?, notification: Notification) {

        var neededDuration: Duration = Duration.ZERO
        val dayOfWeekIndex = getDayOfWeekLocalized(notification.date)

        coroutineScope {

            val dayDuration = launch {
                weekUseCases.getAllWeeks()
                    .collect { weekResponse ->
                        when (weekResponse) {
                            is Response.Failure -> {
                                coroutineContext.cancel()
                            }

                            is Response.Loading -> {}
                            is Response.Success -> {
                                val week =
                                    weekResponse.data?.firstOrNull {
                                        it.week == getWeekOfYearByLocalDate(
                                            notification.date
                                        ) && it.year == notification.date.year
                                    }
                                if (week != null) {
                                    val stringValue = week.weekDailyDurations

                                    val splitString = stringValue.split(":")

                                    val intList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
                                    if (splitString.count() == 7) {

                                        splitString.forEach {
                                            try {
                                                intList.add(it.toInt())
                                            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                                                println("Error: $it is not a valid integer")
                                                coroutineContext.cancel()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    neededDuration = intList[dayOfWeekIndex].minutes
                                } else {
                                    settingsUseCases.getSetting(SettingsIndex.WeekDailyDurations.getIndex())
                                        .collect { response ->
                                            when (response) {
                                                is Response.Failure -> {
                                                    coroutineContext.cancel()
                                                }

                                                is Response.Loading -> {}
                                                is Response.Success -> {
                                                    val stringValue = response.data?.stringValue

                                                    if (stringValue.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                                                        coroutineContext.cancel()
                                                    } else {

                                                        val splitString = stringValue.split(":")
                                                        val intList: MutableList<Int> =
                                                            mutableListOf()
                                                        if (splitString.count() == 7) {

                                                            splitString.forEach {
                                                                try {
                                                                    intList.add(it.toInt())
                                                                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                                                                    println("Error: $it is not a valid integer")
                                                                    coroutineContext.cancel()
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        neededDuration = intList[dayOfWeekIndex].minutes
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            val notificationCreator = launch {
                if (neededDuration != Duration.ZERO) {
                    dayUseCases.getAllDays()
                        .collect { dayResponse ->
                            when (dayResponse) {
                                is Response.Failure -> {
                                    coroutineContext.cancel()
                                }

                                is Response.Loading -> {}
                                is Response.Success -> {
                                    if (dayResponse.data != null) {
                                        val foundDay =
                                            dayResponse.data.firstOrNull { it.date == notification.date && it.isActive }
                                        if (foundDay == null) {
                                            notificationUseCases.getAllNotifications()
                                                .collect { notificationResponse ->
                                                    when (notificationResponse) {
                                                        is Response.Failure -> {
                                                            coroutineContext.cancel()
                                                        }

                                                        is Response.Loading -> {}
                                                        is Response.Success -> {
                                                            if (notificationResponse.data != null) {
                                                                val dayReminderNotification =
                                                                    notificationResponse.data.firstOrNull { it.date == notification.date && it.notificationType == NotificationType.DayUnchangedReminder.value }
                                                                if (dayReminderNotification == null) {
                                                                    notificationUseCases.upsertNotification(
                                                                        notification
                                                                    )
                                                                    context?.let {
                                                                        DayReminderNotificationService(
                                                                            it
                                                                        )
                                                                    }
                                                                        ?.showNotification(
                                                                            notification.title + neededDuration.toFloatHours(),
                                                                            notification.description,
                                                                            notification.notificationType
                                                                        )
                                                                }
                                                                coroutineContext.cancel()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        }
                                        coroutineContext.cancel()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    coroutineContext.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Please [edit] your question to explain why you even need coroutines here. I.e., why not just remove coroutineScope and both launches? Then the code would be executed sequentially. Also, please make sure your code sample can be executed so we can reproduce the issue. Either add everything that is missing, or - better yet - remove everything that is not strictly necessary. In short, make it a [mre].

When you want things to run one after another, you just don't use launch in the first place.
